# XML Deserialization performance in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, serialization

I have a MVC 2 web application that will have a high volume of users. One page in particular will be rendered based on XML from a database table. I was hoping to use de-serialization to parse the XML into an object tree for easier access to the data. However I'm not so sure that this will perform well enough for my users. Is there any other methods to parse the XML that will have better performance implications? I'm not that familiar with XSLT but is that a viable option?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Your question is too vague. First, you need to know **if** there is a performance bottleneck, and if yes, where—at least approximately—it's located. Then you can think of optimizations and/or different approaches to solving that particular problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I was assuming that deserialization would be the bottleneck. Trying to be proactive because once the system is live we can't afford to take it down to fix performance bottleneck. I was seeking some alternatives for parsing the xml without using deserialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided to go with the xslt transformation. Problem solved.